# Why is cornerRadii parameter of CGSize type in -[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:byRoundingCorners:cornerRadii:]?

Tags: ios, uikit, uibezierpath

I can't figure this out... I'm playing with

`-[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:byRoundingCorners:cornerRadii:]` as such:

```
bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(10, 10, 80, 80)
                                   byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerBottomLeft)
                                         cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(20, 20)];
```

And it works as expected. But if I replace cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(20, 20) with, say, `cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(20, 5)` or `CGSizeMake(20, 40)`, there's no difference.

Why is cornerRadii `CGSize` and not `CGFloat` then? What is `CGSize.height` for?

Any ideas and advice will be greatly appreciated :)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, after further tests I finally found that it seems to be an iOS 7 bug. The same code on iOS 6 simulator draws properly, as expected. however, both iOS 7 simulator and iOS 7 device have this issue and draw improperly.

I'll file a bug report, unless someone proves me wrong and there is something I am missing.

Comment: I filed a bug report on this as well. Apple claims that this is a deliberate change and that iOS >=7 is working as designed. I say bulls**t. The new version of `bezierPathWithRoundedRect:byRoundingCorners:cornerRadii:` always ignores the height parameter and your corners are always quarter-circles. Under iOS <= 6, you could get oval corners, but you can't any more. Apple is full of it on this one. They broke a working function.

Answer (score 7):

I can now confirm that this is a bug introduced after iOS 6. I have an old 4s running iOS 6.1. On that machine, this code:

```
  path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: bounds
    byRoundingCorners: UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight
   cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(bounds.size.width/2, bounds.size.width/6)
 ];
```

Creates a rounded rectangle with the corners oval-shaped. The curve is much more gradual on the top part of the curve, and much sharper on the sides, as you would expect:

This is the iOS 6.1 image, with the corners as they should be:
[image: This is the iOS 6.1 image, with the corners as they should be]

And here is what the same code looks like when run from iOS 8.1.2:
[image]

It appears that on iOS >=7.0, it ignores the height of the specified radius and uses the width value for both the height and the width of the corner ovals, which forces them to always be quarter circles.

I've logged a bug on apple's bug reporter system. We'll see what they say.
I suggest everybody else who's seeing this problem report a bug also. The more reports they get, the more likely they are to fix it.

Comment: This appears to still be a problem even using Swift on iOS 9+

Answer (score 1):

The `CGSize` parameter is to allow the corner radii on the the horizontal and vertical planes to be different. i.e. a non-symmetrical corners.

Try turning on different corners and using different values to see what happens.

Comment: That's what I expected too.I followed your advice and set to round all corners as well as some other options and still, same result. It's just as if is used only CGSize.width value and ignored .height

Comment: Well, it should change the shape of the corner. Is the code you show the actual code for the images (the corner size compared to the rect size)?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem. I added extension UIBezier that implement RoundedRect with correct rounded corners - **Radii**. It implementation doesn't discard vertical radius. You can use oval rounded corners.

https://github.com/BuTaJIuK-ua/UIBezierPath-Extension

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34496332)