# UIBezierPath Init() doesnt expect byRoundingCorners parameter

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

Can't seem to use the typical init for UIBezierPath that contains the parameter byRoundingCorners parameter:

```
    var maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: headerView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: (UIRectCorner.TopLeft | UIRectCorner.TopRight), cornerRadii: 5.0)
```

Gives the error "Extra argument 'byRoundingCorners in call"

Is this a Swift bug?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is a Swift bug in so far as the error message is quite misleading.
The real error is that the `cornerRadii` parameter has the type `CGSize`,
but you are passing a floating point number (compare [Why is cornerRadii parameter of CGSize type in -[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:byRoundingCorners:cornerRadii:]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880919/why-is-cornerradii-parameter-of-cgsize-type-in-uibezierpath-bezierpathwithroun)).

This should work (Swift 1.2):

```
var maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: headerView.bounds,
            byRoundingCorners: .TopLeft | .TopRight,
            cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0))
```

Note that in Swift 2, the type of byRoundingCorners argument was changed to `OptionSetType`:

```
var maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: headerView.bounds,
            byRoundingCorners: [.TopLeft, .TopRight],
            cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0))
```

Comment: This is the good answer for swift 2. I searched a lot till I have found it. You saved my day. Thanx a lot.