# UIBezierPath rounded corners in UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uibezierpath

I want to draw a tappable bubble shape around text. In order to do that I decided to add a shapelayer to UIButton like this:

```
// Button also has this
bubbleButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 10, bottom: 5, right: 10)
bubbleButton.setTitle("Gutp", for: .normal)

// In my subclass of UIButton
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    self.bubbleLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()

    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer.init()
    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: self.bounds,
                                       byRoundingCorners: [.topRight, .topLeft, .bottomLeft],
                                       cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20))
    maskLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath
    maskLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    maskLayer.lineWidth = 2
    maskLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    maskLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    maskLayer.isOpaque = false

    self.bubbleLayer = maskLayer

    if let layers = self.layer.sublayers {
        self.layer.insertSublayer(self.bubbleLayer!, at: UInt32(layers.count))
    } else {
        self.layer.addSublayer(self.bubbleLayer!)
    }
}
```

Please don't look at the performance at the moment.

I have 2 buttons like this added into a UIStackView.

I get an interesting artefact (a tail if one can say so) in some cases of text (usually when it is short) and a normal bubble in case of longer text:[image: bezierpath-artefact]

How can I fix this? And why do I get such behavior?

EDIT: Linking other possibly related questions about broken cornerRadii parameter in bezierPathWithRoundedRect:byRoundingCorners:cornerRadii:. Maybe it will help someone with similar issues.

1. [Why is cornerRadii parameter of CGSize type in -[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:byRoundingCorners:cornerRadii:]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880919/why-is-cornerradii-parameter-of-cgsize-type-in-uibezierpath-bezierpathwithroun)
2. [Crazy rounded rect UIBezierPath behavior on iOS 7. What is the deal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936003/crazy-rounded-rect-uibezierpath-behavior-on-ios-7-what-is-the-deal)

Comment: Could it be that your button height is too low? Due to corner radius being 20 it needs to be at least 40. But generally I dislike these high level methods for paths, I would create it manually with lines and arcs.

Comment: @MaticOblak yes, thank you for the hint. It seems that `UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect` is broken. If I check my radius to not be larger than a half size of the smallest side it works as expected. If you want you can write as an answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For using these rounded rect methods you must ensure that the view size is larger then the radius used. In your case both width and height must be larger then 40 (Radii size is 20x20 so `max(20*2, 20*2) = 40`).

In general I prefer having a custom method to generate such paths. Using lines and arcs usually give you better flexibility. You may try the following:

```
    /// Returns a path with rounded corners
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - frame: A frame at which the path is drawn. To fit in view "bounds" should be used
    ///   - maximumRadius: A maximum corner radius used. For smaller views radius will be min(width/2, height/2)
    /// - Returns: Returns a new path
    func roundedRectPath(inRect frame: CGRect, radiusConstrainedTo maximumRadius: CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {

        let radisu = min(maximumRadius, min(frame.size.width*0.5, frame.size.height*0.5))

        let path = UIBezierPath()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: frame.origin.x + radisu, y: frame.origin.y)) // Top left
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.origin.x + frame.size.width - radisu, y: frame.origin.y))  // Top right
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.origin.x + frame.size.width, y: frame.origin.y + frame.size.height - radisu), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: frame.origin.x + frame.size.width, y: frame.origin.y)) // Top right arc
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.origin.x + frame.size.width, y: frame.origin.y + frame.size.height - radisu))  // Bottom right
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.origin.x + frame.size.width - radisu, y: frame.origin.y + frame.size.height), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: frame.origin.x + frame.size.width, y: frame.origin.y + frame.size.height)) // Bottom right arc
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.origin.x + radisu, y: frame.origin.y + frame.size.height))  // Bottom left
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.origin.x, y: frame.origin.y + frame.size.height - radisu), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: frame.origin.x, y: frame.origin.y + frame.size.height)) // Bottom left arc
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.origin.x, y: frame.origin.y + radisu))  // Top left
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.origin.x + radisu, y: frame.origin.y), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: frame.origin.x, y: frame.origin.y)) // Top left arc
        path.close()

        return path
    }
```

When using this with stroke you need to also inset the frame by half of the line width. This is a snippet from "draw rect" procedure but can be applied anywhere:

```
        UIColor.red.setStroke()
        let lineWidth: CGFloat = 5.0
        let path = roundedRectPath(inRect: bounds.insetBy(dx: lineWidth*0.5, dy: lineWidth*0.5), radiusConstrainedTo: 30.0)
        path.lineWidth = lineWidth
        path.stroke()
```

Notice the `bounds.insetBy(dx: lineWidth*0.5, dy: lineWidth*0.5)`.

Comment: I have found a couple of questions related to broken roundedRect: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880919/why-is-cornerradii-parameter-of-cgsize-type-in-uibezierpath-bezierpathwithroun and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936003/crazy-rounded-rect-uibezierpath-behavior-on-ios-7-what-is-the-deal

Comment: @iur Interesting. So this practically never worked. Anyway I edited the answer to add the insets for the line width when stroking the control.

Comment: Thanks. I don't care much about lines going out of button frame, but it should be definitely useful for someone.

Comment: @iur The path may be clipped depending on the settings which would make the line appear thinner on the sides then the line drawing the corner.

Comment: @iur In other words: I suggest you to use this so it won't break your code in the future if your view gets clipped or your layout changes so that it interacts with the stroke since it goes out of bounds.

Comment: Yeah, path insets will definitely go into production code. As well as optimisations of not creating layer each time :). I didn't want to overload the question with irrelevant details.